# Existence of a normal p-Sylow subgroup when $\lvert\mkern1mu G\mkern1mu \rvert=q^{2}\mkern1mu p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $\lvert\,G\,\rvert=p^{2}\cdot\,q$ where $q,p$ are primes, How can i show $G$ has a normal p-sylow subgroup ?
I tried working with the sylow theorem but i cant reach any contradiction when $Np = q$ and $Nq = p,p^2$
Also tried searching the same question but couldn't find in Stack Exchange

Comment: If the order of $G$ equals the product of two primes then we know that $G$ has a normal subgroup of prime order equal to the prime divisor because the group may be generated by that prime.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems Theorem 3

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC okay, Sorry forgot to say, It need to be a p-syllow subgroup

Comment: @zkzkzkzkzk the number of q-sylow subgroups being denotated by Nq, from the 3rd theorem It has to divide $p^2$, so $ Nq= 1,p$ or $p^2$

Comment: It should be $n_p=1,q,q^2$ and $n_q=1,p$.

Comment: @lhf yes Sorry messed up notation haha

Comment: Is there any relation between $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @Bernard nop, they are primes, bezout theorem could be used as they are also relatively primes

Comment: I thought of something like $p<q<2p$, for instance.

Comment: @Bernard there is not something like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false for $q=2, p=3$. The $3$-Sylow subgroups of $A_4$ are not normal: there are four copies of $A_3$ in $A_4$.

Comment: But are 2-syllow not normal also? Only one of them need to be

Comment: @user528821, that's not what your question says. Ask a separate question fixing this.

Comment: Abused notation Will fix It, was meaning p as any prime

Comment: Had already edited but opened a New one